# php: inconsistent behaviour with HTTP headers

Tags: php, url, http-headers, http-status-code-404, httpresponse

am testing lots of links on the same domain to see whether they exist or not. I am using the following code:

```
function get_http_response_code($url)
{
    $headers = get_headers($url);
    return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
}

function getURLs()
{
    foreach($allResults as $result)
    {
    $tempURL = 'http://www.doma.in/foo/'.$result.'/bar';
    if(get_http_response_code($tempURL) != "404" && get_http_response_code($tempURL) != "500")
    {
        $URLs[] = $tempURL;
    }
    else
    {
        echo $tempURL.' could not be reached<br />';
    }
    return $URLs;
}
$URLs = getURLs();
```

The problem is, among the hundreds that do exist, the `$URLs` array contains URLs that do not exist (404); sometimes two, sometimes four, but every time it produces an HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found error. Why such variance? Is there a timeout I should be setting? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't $url variable in Your getURLs function scope.

Comment: thanks, typo, edited. this code is heavily edited but the problem is still how I have described it.

Comment: Can you see the errors in the server log?

Comment: Which log would that be? I am using Apache.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from Your code the problem is in mistake of variable `$url`
Try this.

```
...
foreach($allResults as $result)
{
    $tempURL = 'http://www.doma.in/foo/'.$result['url'].'/bar';
...
```

`$url` changed to `$result`

Comment: the code itself works. I am having problems with HTTP headers.